# Null reference exception when initializing Android Driver iWebElement via class method

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I'm getting a null reference exception when trying to initialize an instance of AndroidDriver iWebElement in a class method that is dedicated to that purpose. I'm able to initialize in Program Main.

This is my AndroidDriver class which contains the `LaunchApp()` method that I created to initialize an instand of `AndroidDriver<iWebElement>` this method fails with a null reference exception error:

------ Not Working :( ------

```
public class AndroidDriver : AppiumService
{
    public AppiumOptions capabilities;
    public static AndroidDriver<IWebElement> driver;
    public AndroidDriver LaunchApp(string platformName, string platformVersion, string automationName, string deviceName, string appPath)
    {
        capabilities = new AppiumOptions();
        capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:platformName",platformName);
        capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:platformVersion", platformVersion);
        capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:automationName", automationName);
        capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:deviceName", deviceName);
        capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:app", appPath);
 
        driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(service, capabilities);           
 
         return this;
     }
 }
```

Stack Trace:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumCommandExecutor..ctor(AppiumLocalService service, TimeSpan timeForTheServerResponding)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1..ctor(AppiumLocalService service, ICapabilities appiumOptions)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android.AndroidDriver`1..ctor(AppiumLocalService service, DriverOptions driverOptions)
at AppiumAndroid.Actions.AndroidDriver.LaunchApp(String platformName, String platformVersion, String automationName, String deviceName, String appPath) in C:\Automation\AppiumAndroid\AppiumAndroid\Actions\AndroidDriver.cs:line 32
at AppiumAndroid.Tests.SmokeTest.Launch_Barcode_Scanning_Configure() in C:\Automation\AppiumAndroid\AppiumAndroid\Tests\SmokeTest.cs:line 47
```

I'm able to initialize an instance of `AndroidDriver<iWebElement>` in Program Main and it works fine. In the code below I am passing hard-coded strings for each capability, while I'm using string variables from a class used to store Appium Capabilities configurations. Not sure if that's  :

------ Working ------

```
AppiumOptions capabilities = new AppiumOptions(); 
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Android"); 
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("platformVersion", "11"); 
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:automationName", "UIAutomator2"); 
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:app", "C:\AppPath\App.apk");

//Launch Test AndroidDriver<IWebElement> driver; driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(service, capabilities);
```

I excpected an instance of `AdroidDriver<iWebElement>` to be launched by the `LaunchApp()` method.

I tried updating my version of Selenium WebDriver but that actually caused the `AndroidDriver<iWebElement>` class to not work...(version compatability issue?).

Comment: what is the "service" reference pointing to in both of these cases? Debug at the point of the exception and check all references to determine if anything is null. Also your working  example is setting capability values of things like "platformName" rather than "appium:platformName" etc. Is this a case where there is a mismatch of parameter settings where it is expecting particular values?